# How to detect headset buttons? How to detect bluetooth headset buttons? android studio

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, mp3, headphones

I want to make an mp3 player for android. This is my first app and I have no idea how to get anything related to the button on the headphones. Thank you in advance

Comment: Try reading [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/mediabuttons). It seems similar to handling any other KeyEvent, except the keys you're looking for indicate that play/pause/next has been pressed.

Comment: KeyEvent works only if activity is opened, isn't it?

Comment: If you're referring to using media controls even if the app is closed, I think [this article](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-controls) goes into that problem.

Comment: I just need to skip song, if i punch button on my headset

Comment: You won't be implementing any direct response to buttons on an external device. Android itself will take care of how pressing pause/play/next on your headphones will result in a signal being fed into your app. So you just need to worry about programming how your app responds to receiving a pause/play/next event as per the articles I linked.